# Should I use who or whom here?

Tags: whom, who

> My friend was eaten by a giant snail **who** is afraid of the dark.

Should I use “who” or “whom” here?

EDIT:

If I wanted to specify that my friend was afraid of the dark, then would I use “who”? If I wanted to specify that the snail was afraid of the dark, then would I use “whom”?

Comment: Do you know what the difference between _who_ and _whom_ is? What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: My understanding is that “who” refers to the subject, and “whom” refers to the object. @Heartspring

Comment: *Who* and just move on… 'All hope abandon ye who enter here.'

Comment: Neither *who* nor *whom* means that your friend is afraid of the dark: For that, you would write: "My friend who was afraid of the dark was eaten by a giant snail."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the relative clause is part of the subject or the object of the sentence as a whole. What matters is the role *who/whom* within the relative clause itself. In this case, *who* is the subject of *is,* so you would not use *whom* here.

Comment: That perspective makes sense. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to refer to the snail's fear of the dark and you wanted to preserve the exact syntax, I would default to the pronoun "that," as I try to limit my use of "who/whom" to people -- although perhaps that is now a dated norm.

Here's a link that explores the who/that option: https://www.latimes.com/socal/daily-pilot/opinion/tn-dpt-me-0612-casagrande-20140611-story.html

Comment: Why not *which*?

Comment: Because that would change the spirit of the syntax, as "which" normally invites a comma before it when used as a relative pronoun. That said, this convention is maybe something we no longer seek to universally uphold.

Comment: I think it that it is now recognised that *which* has always been used by the finest writers in the language for defining (aka *restricted* or *integrated*) relative clauses, and that that rule was invented by self-regarding fantasists! [A day which will live in infamy](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4357). However, a +1 from me for an otherwise helpful suggestion. (Note that the syntax is more different if you use *that*)!)